# Текстура уничтожается слишком рано?

Tags: c++, sfml, imgui

```cpp
// Sprite.
if(ImGui::CollapsingHeader("Sprite.")) {
    // Preview texture allocations.
    sf::Texture texture;

    // ...

    static char spritePath[MAX_OBJECTS_TEXT_SIZE / 2]; // (512 / 2)

    // ...

    if(ImGui::InputText("Sprite path.##sprite", spritePath, IM_ARRAYSIZE(spritePath))) {
        texture.loadFromFile(spritePath); // <- загрузка
    }

    // ...

    // Preview. (150, 150).
    ImGui::Image(texture, sf::Vector2f(DEFAULT_TEXTURE_PREVIEW_WIDTH, DEFAULT_TEXTURE_PREVIEW_HEIGHT), sf::Color::Transparent, sf::Color::White);
}
```

В результате получается пустой квадрат:

[image]

example.png - точно существует и ошибок нету (о том что не удалось загрузить текстуру).

Из документации SFML -

> Вы успешно загрузили текстуру, правильно построили спрайт, и... теперь все, что вы видите на своем экране, это белый квадрат. Что случилось?
>
> Это распространенная ошибка. Когда вы устанавливаете текстуру спрайта, все, что он внутри делает, это сохраняет указатель на экземпляр текстуры. Поэтому, если текстура уничтожается или перемещается в другое место в памяти, спрайт оказывается с недопустимым указателем текстуры.

```cpp
sf::Sprite loadSprite(std::string filename)
{
    sf::Texture texture;
    texture.loadFromFile(filename);

    return sf::Sprite(texture);
} // error: the texture is destroyed here (ошибка: спрайт уничтожен сдесь)
```

Я не понимаю почему текстура уничтожается, если я ее создал в одном блоке if? и как сделать что бы она не уничтожалась?

P.S: Функция ImGui::Image - рисует изображение в следующием кадре, а уже в следущем кадре текстура удаляется, как сделать чтобы она не удалялась?

UPD:

```cpp
sf::Texture texture;

while(window.isOpen()) {
    // Sprite.
    if(ImGui::CollapsingHeader("Sprite.")) {
        if(ImGui::InputText("Sprite path.##sprite", spritePath, IM_ARRAYSIZE(spritePath))) {
            if(!texture.loadFromFile(spritePath)) {
                LevelDesignerLog::consoleLog("Failed to show sprite preview.");
            } else {
                LevelDesignerLog::consoleLog("Loaded sprite preview successfully.");
            }
        }

        // ...

        // Create sprite.
        if(ImGui::Button("Create sprite.")) {
            LevelObject sprite;

            sprite.lobjecttype = LevelObjectType::SPRITE;

            sprite.lobjectname = objectName;

            sprite.objectSWidth = spriteWidth;
            sprite.objectSHeight = spriteHeight;

            sprite.objectX = spriteX;
            sprite.objectY = spriteY;

            sprite.spritePath = spritePath;

            objectsBuffer.addObject(sprite);

            LevelDesignerLog::consoleLog("Sprite '" + std::string(objectName) + "' created.");
        }

        // Preview.
        ImGui::Image(texture, sf::Vector2f(DEFAULT_TEXTURE_PREVIEW_WIDTH, DEFAULT_TEXTURE_PREVIEW_HEIGHT), sf::Color::Transparent, sf::Color::White);
    }
}
```

Сделал обявление текстуры перед циклом, не помогло

Comment: *"как сделать чтобы она не удалялась"* Ну, положить в какую-то переменную, которая доживет до следующего кадра? Вы же не собираетесь каждый кадр ее перезагружать из файла?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, Так я и не перезагружаю каждый раз, я перегружаю текстуру (loadFromFile) только когда Input обновляется, и я пытался положить текстуру за начало цикла, все равно не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У локальных переменных в стеке (те, которые создаются не через `new()`) ограниченное время жизни. И при этом ограничено оно блоком кода

```cpp
if(ImGui::CollapsingHeader("Sprite.")) {
    // Preview texture allocations.
    sf::Texture texture; // <- Выделяется память на стеке для текстуры

    ...

    ImGui::Image(texture, sf::Vector2f(DEFAULT_TEXTURE_PREVIEW_WIDTH, DEFAULT_TEXTURE_PREVIEW_HEIGHT), sf::Color::Transparent, sf::Color::White);
} // <- Блок кода if закрывается, 
  // следовательно все переменные в данном блоке удаляются
  // и память с текстурой освобождается
  // вызывая у текстуры ~Texture() который удаляет сам объект текстуры в куче
```

А отрисовка скорее всего происходит в отдельном потоке, из за чего `texture` используется уже после того, как он был удалён

Да и загружать текстуру каждый кадр плохая идея

Вам стоит вынести переменную `sf::Texture texture` куда ни будь за пределы цикла кадра (например в класс, в котором это всё обрабатывается), а `texture.loadFromFile(...)` вынести перед циклом (там где всё инициализируется)

**UPDATED!!!**

Возможно в IMGUI текстуры надо хранить на куче

(**UPDATED2!!!** я ошибся, текстуру можно хранить на стеке, главное в нужном месте):

```cpp
sf::Texture texture;
// Заменяй на
sf::Texture* texture = new sf::Texture();

!texture.loadFromFile(spritePath)
// Заменяй на 
!texture->loadFromFile(spritePath)

ImGui::Image(texture, ...)
// Заменяй на
ImGui::Image(*texture, ...)
```

Comment: Я пытался переместить Texture перед началом цикла, не помогло, и я загружаю текстуру как только Input обновляется, а не каждый кадр

Comment: @sad Может лучше обновлять когда нажимается кнопка Create Sprite? А ещё, вы не могли бы показать весь код залив его например на pastebin

Comment: тогда от механики превью текстуры нету никакой пользы, а код слишком большой, но я обновил вопрос

Comment: @sad Опять же, вынесите её за пределы цикла обработки кадров, и загружайте текстуру только когда она обновляется

Comment: https://pastebin.com/4K3UPNtp, вот немного расширенный код, вынес текстуру за цикл, не помогло

Comment: @sad ошибка та же?

Comment: та же, показывает что успешно загрузило текстуру но текстура в окошке не отображается, в общем та же

Comment: @sad Короче я не нашёл другого решния, всё что ты можешь, так это попробовать кинуть текстуру на кучу. Щас обновлю ответ

Comment: @sad Я обновил свой ответ

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/3LaXz7w.png - та же проблема
все заменил и еще вынес создание текстуры перед циклом, не работает(

Comment: @sad Тогда я не знаю, с IMGUI не работал, ждите тех, кто разбирается в этой теме лучше меня

Comment: сейчас и сам попробую что то делать

Comment: я решил проблему, оказывается tintColor (аргумент в имгуи::имадж) не только устанавливает цвет для заднего фона, но и для текстуры, а этот тинт колор был у меня прозрачный, значит и текстура и задний фон были прозрачные, но возомжно это только пол проблемы, и в решение еще сыграл ваш ответ (хранить текстуру на стеке). спасибо вам большое, поставлю ваш ответ решением когда смогу войти в аккаунт

Comment: @sad ахахах, бывает) ладно удачи вам

Comment: В последнем варианте текстура утекает, нет?

Comment: `ImGui::Image(*texture` - выглядит как будто тут вызывается конструктор копирования и на область видимости текстуры вообще пофиг? Впрочем, я документацию нагуглить не смог, так что теоретически там может быть ссылка на текстуру...

Comment: ImGui::Image(const sf::Texture& texture, const sf::Color& tintColor, const sf::Color& borderColor) - Документации для этого метода нету

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается, третий аргумент `tintColor` в `ImGui::Image` окрашивает не только задний фон, но и саму текстуру, и этот `tintColor` я сделал прозрачным, не зная, что это делает текстуру также прозрачной.

И еще сделал, чтобы текстура хранилась на стеке, и теперь все заработало.

[image]